# Printing Dynamic Data

Tags: haskell, generics, types

I have a system in haskell that uses Data.Dynamic and Type.Reflection to perform inference and calculations. I would like to be able to print the results.

Printing is easy when the type is supplied e.g

```
foo :: Dynamic -> String
foo dyn = case tyConName . someTypeRepTyCon . dynTypeRep $ dyn of
             "Int"  -> show $ fromDyn dyn (0 :: Int)
             "Bool" -> show $ fromDyn dyn True
             _      -> "no chance"
```

But if I want to be able to print tuples, I would have to add a new line for each e.g (Int, Bool), (Bool, Int), (Char, Int, Banana) ....

With the addition of more primitives and larger tuples this quickly becomes impractical.

**Is there an algorithmic way to generate strings for this dynamic data, specifically for tuples and lists.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the main idea of the other answer, but it seems to get where it's going in a fairly roundabout way. Here's how I would style the same idea:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
import Type.Reflection
import Data.Dynamic

showDyn :: Dynamic -> String
showDyn (Dynamic (App (App (eqTypeRep (typeRep @(,)) -> Just HRefl) ta) tb) (va, vb))
    = concat [ "DynamicPair("
             , showDyn (Dynamic ta va)
             , ","
             , showDyn (Dynamic tb vb)
             , ")"
             ]
showDyn (Dynamic (eqTypeRep (typeRep @Integer) -> Just HRefl) n) = show n
showDyn (Dynamic tr _) = show tr
```

That first pattern match is quite a mouthful, but after playing with a few different ways of formatting it I'm convinced that there just is no way to make that look good. You can try it in ghci:

```
> showDyn (toDyn ((3,4), (True, "hi")))
"DynamicPair(DynamicPair(3,4),DynamicPair(Bool,[Char]))"
```

Answer (score 2):

I could only manage to obtain this horrible solution.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}
{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}

import Type.Reflection
import Data.Dynamic
```

Here we define the `TyCon` for `(,)` and `Int`. (I'm pretty sure there must be an easier way.)

```
pairTyCon :: TyCon
pairTyCon = someTypeRepTyCon (someTypeRep [('a','b')])

intTyCon :: TyCon
intTyCon = someTypeRepTyCon (someTypeRep [42 :: Int])
```

Then we dissect the `Dynamic` type. First we check if it is an `Int`.

```
showDynamic :: Dynamic -> String
showDynamic x = case x of
   Dynamic tr@(Con k) v | k == intTyCon ->
      case eqTypeRep tr (typeRep @ Int) of
        Just HRefl -> show (v :: Int)
        _ -> error "It really should be an int"
   -- to be continued
```

The above is ugly, since we first pattern match against the `TyCon` using `==` instead of pattern matching, which prevents the type refinement of `v` into an `Int`. So, we still have to resort to `eqTypeRep` to perform a second check which we already know has to succeed.

I think it could be made pretty by checking `eqTypeRep` in advance, for instance. Or `fromDyn`. It does not matter.

What matters is that the pair case below is even more messy, and can not be made pretty in the same way, as far as I can see.

```
   -- continuing from above
   Dynamic tr@(App (App t0@(Con k :: TypeRep p)
            (t1 :: TypeRep a1))
            (t2 :: TypeRep a2)) v | k == pairTyCon ->
      withTypeable t0 $
      withTypeable t1 $
      withTypeable t2 $
      case ( eqTypeRep tr (typeRep @(p a1 a2))
           , eqTypeRep (typeRep @p) (typeRep @(,))) of
        (Just HRefl, Just HRefl) ->
            "DynamicPair("
            ++ showDynamic (Dynamic t1 (fst v))
            ++ ", "
            ++ showDynamic (Dynamic t2 (snd v))
            ++ ")"
        _ -> error "It really should be a pair!"
   _ -> "Dynamic: not an int, not a pair"
```

Above we match the `TypeRep` so that it represents something of type `p a1 a2`. We require that the representation of `p` to be `pairTyCon`.

As before this does not trigger type refinement, since it is done with `==` instead of pattern matching. We need to perform another explicit match to force `p ~ (,)` and another for the final refinement `v :: (a1,a2)`. Sigh.

Finally, we can take `fst v` and `snd v`, turn them into `Dynamic` once again, and pair them. Effectively, we turned the original `x :: Dynamic` into something like `(fst x, snd x)` where both components are `Dynamic`. Now we can recurse.

I would really like to avoid the `error`s, but I can not see how to do that at the moment.

The redeeming part is that the approach is very general, and can be easily adapted to other type constructors.

Comment: There's a function for getting a string rep of the constructor, tyConName that I've been using for testing constructor types. (still reading your answer)

Comment: Works well thanks. I think the main issue I was having was forgetting to use withTypeable.