# Generating Dynamic Data Randomly

Tags: haskell, generics, types

I have a system in haskell that uses Data.Dynamic and Type.Reflection to perform inference and calculations. I would like to be able to generate dynamic data randomly.

Generating dynamic data is easy when the type is known.

```
goo :: SomeTypeRep -> IO (Dynamic)
goo str = case tyConName . someTypeRepTyCon $ str of
            "Int"  -> return . toDyn . randomRIO $ (-20, 100::Int)
            "Bool" -> return . toDyn . randomRIO $ (True, False)
            _      -> error "no chance"
```

But having a new line for every type is impractical when handling tuples.

**Is there a way to combine n dynamics into a tuple? Or is there another way to generate the tuples dynamically?**

Comment: Answer is likely related to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48951745/printing-dynamic-data) I posted earlier

Comment: I don't think that code does what you think it does. `return . toDyn . randomRIO $ (-20, 100)` does not create a random `Int`, convert it to `Dynamic`, and return that value. It converts *the `IO` action that creates a random `Int`* to `Dynamic`. You almost certainly want `toDyn <$> randomRIO (-20, 100)` instead (and similarly for the next line).

Answer (score 3):

Generally when working with `Type.Reflection` you want to leave your quantification as "late" as possible. With that in mind, the following seems to work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Dynamic
import System.Random
import Type.Reflection

goo :: TypeRep a -> IO a
goo tr = case tr of
    App (App comma a) b | Just HRefl <- eqTypeRep (typeRep @(,)) comma
        -> liftA2 (,) (goo a) (goo b)
    _ | Just HRefl <- eqTypeRep (typeRep @Int) tr -> randomRIO (-20, 100)
      | Just HRefl <- eqTypeRep (typeRep @Bool) tr -> randomIO
      | otherwise -> fail "dunno lol"
```

You might object that you want to take an existing `Dynamic` and produce a new, matching, random one, and that this doesn't work:

```
gooBad :: Dynamic -> IO Dynamic
gooBad d = case dynTypeRep d of
    SomeTypeRep tr -> toDyn <$> goo tr
```

That's true: the `SomeTypeRep` type existentially quantifies over the *kind* of its `TypeRep`, which is unfortunate, since we know that it's going to be representing a type of kind `*`. Luckily, `Data.Dynamic` exports enough information to do it yourself without `dynTypeRep`:

```
gooDyn :: Dynamic -> IO Dynamic
gooDyn (Dynamic tr _) = Dynamic tr <$> goo tr
```

Comment: It looks like there's also `typeRepKind :: TypeRep (a :: k) -> TypeRep k`, so if it's *really* necessary to take a `SomeTypeRep` as the argument for some reason it looks like it should be possible with a bit of hand-wringing. Let me know if that seems useful and I can write a few comments about that.

Comment: Hey I'm not sure why but I'm getting some errors when trying to compile goo. [link](https://imgur.com/a/DZNzs) any ideas?

Comment: @TheJohnMajor01 Whoops, that's embarrassing. Must have introduced that while trying out some alternate formattings. Should be fixed -- it was just a parenthesis that had migrated.