# RPC (Or: How do I disambiguate function application based on TypeRep values?)

Tags: haskell, serialization, types, rpc, existential-type

I'm building some infrastructure for doing remote procedure calls in Haskell, and for reasons that are too long to explain here, I cannot reuse existing libraries.

So here's the setup: I have a type class for serializing and deserializing data:

```
class Serializable a where
  encode :: a -> B.ByteString
  decode :: B.ByteString -> Maybe a
  maxSize :: a -> Int
```

where `B` is [Data.ByteString](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString.html).

I can use this to implement serialization of integers, booleans, lists of serializables, tuples of serializables ect.

Now I want to send some arguments across a network to a server, which then performs a computation based on these arguments, and sends back a result. So I create an existential type representing things that can be serialized:

```
data SerializableExt = forall t . Serializable t => SerializableExt t
```

because I want to send something of type `[SerializableExt]`.

So, of course, I need to create an instance `Serializable SerializableExt`. This is where the problem starts:

In order to implement `decode :: B.ByteString -> Maybe SerializableExt` I need to know the concrete type that the existential type SerializableExt wraps.

So I implement `encode :: SerializableExt -> B.ByteString` as serializing the concrete type along with the value:

```
encode (SerializableExt x) = encode (typeOf x, x)
```

using `typeOf` from [Data-Typeable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html). The problem is now the implementation of `decode :: B.ByteString -> Maybe SerializableExt`:

```
decode bs =
  let (tyenc, xenc) = splitPair bs -- Not really important. It just splits bs into the two components
  in case (decode tyenc :: Maybe TypeRep) of
       Just ty -> SerializableExt <$> _ -- Somehow invoke decode xenc, where the choice of which decode to execute depends on the value of ty.
       _ -> Nothing
```

But I can't see how to fill in the hole here. Because of Haskell's separation of the value level and the type level I can't use the value of ty to disambiguate the invocation of `decode xenc`, right?

Is there a way to solve this issue, and actually put something in the hole which will do what I want? Or can you come up with another design?

EDIT: One way of doing it would be the following:

```
decode bs =
  let (tyenc, xenc) = splitPair bs
  in SerializableExt <$>
       case (decode tyenc :: Maybe TypeRep) of
         Just ty
           | ty == typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy Int) -> decode xenc :: Maybe Int
           | ty = typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy ()) -> decode xenc :: Maybe ()
           | ...
         _ -> Nothing
```

but this is bad for several reasons:

1. It's tedious to extend.
2. It cannot handle pairs (or generally: tuples) generically; every
   combination of types needs to be handled.
3. It's not very Haskelly

Comment: I believe this might be impossible to do in Haskell without some more boilerplate. The point is that, at _runtime_, we would decode the bits into a `TypeRep` for some type `a`, and only then we would need to access the instance for `Serializable a`. To perform this, since `a` is unknown at compile time (and is not passed as an argument, but discovered from bits) we need to have the list of all instances at runtime, something that GHC does not keep around.

Comment: By the way, I also believe that there might be some generic way to handle pairs. You should be able to  check that the `TypeRep` is for a pair type, and get the two `TypeRep`s for the components. After that, one can recurse.

Comment: I had the feeling that this wasn't possible :( Your idea for pairs sounds interesting, however! I'm not sure how I can discover that a TypeRep is for a pair without knowing the specific component types, given that Typeable requires monomorphic types?

Comment: I think you can adapt this technique to check for pairs even if the components are unknown https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48951745/printing-dynamic-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Data.Dynamic` lets us put arbitrary Haskell values into a single container, and get them out again in a type-safe way.  That's a good start towards inter-process communication; I'll come back to serialization below.

We can write a program that takes a list of `Dynamic` values, checks for the number & types it needs, and returns a result in the same way.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
-- | Experiments with type-safe serialization.

module Main where

import Data.Proxy
import Data.Dynamic
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Type.Equality
import Type.Reflection

foo :: Int -> String -> String
foo i s = concat (replicate i s)

actor :: [Dynamic] -> Either String [Dynamic]
actor (di : ds : _) = case (fromDynamic di, fromDynamic ds) of
    (Just i, Just s) -> Right [toDyn (foo i s)]
    _ -> Left "Wrong types of arguments"
actor _ = Left "Not enough arguments"

caller :: Either String [Dynamic]
caller = actor [ toDyn (3::Int), toDyn "bar" ]

main :: IO ()
main = case caller of
    Left err -> putStrLn err
    Right dyns -> for_ dyns (\d -> case fromDynamic d of
                                    Just s -> putStrLn s
                                    Nothing -> print d)
```

We can use a `TypeRep` to guide selection of a class instance.  (For ease of testing my code, I used `String`.)

```
class Serial a where
    encode :: a -> String
    decode :: String -> Maybe a

decodeAs :: Serial a => TypeRep a -> String -> Maybe a
decodeAs _ s = decode s
```

Finally, we'd like to serialize the `TypeRep`, and when decoding, check that the encoded type matches the type that we're decoding at.

```
instance Serial SomeTypeRep

encodeDyn :: (Typeable a, Serial a) => a -> (String, String)
encodeDyn a = (encode (SomeTypeRep (typeOf a)), encode a)

decodeDynamic :: forall a. (Typeable a, Serial a) => String -> String -> Maybe a
decodeDynamic tyStr aStr = case decode tyStr of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just (SomeTypeRep ty) ->
        case eqTypeRep ty (typeRep :: TypeRep a) of
               Nothing -> Nothing
               Just HRefl -> decodeAs ty aStr
```